# Write text from right to left in a text file with php

Tags: php, unicode, arabic, right-to-left, bidi

I would like to write arabic text inside a text file with php but i didn't found how to write the text from right-to-left. I have found this article [understanding-bidirectional-text](http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/)
Where they explain that i should add before my string the unicode character U+202E and U+202C after. But i don't know how to convert this unicode character to string in php. I tried with something like this `$content = "\u{202E}".$content."\u{202C}"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if your client does not support bidirectional behaviour, you need to use force. This often happens in plain text environments. There is an easy way to create such texts in PHP, using these functions:

```
function utf8 ( $codepoint ) {
    // 200E = ltr mark
    // 200F = rtl mark
    return json_decode('"\u'.$codepoint.'"');
}

function rtl ( $string ) {
    return utf8('200f').$string.utf8('200e');
}

function ltr ( $string ) {
    return utf8('200e').$string.utf8('200f');
}
```

The first function translates a unicode utf-8 codepoint. The second function returns a string with right-to-left marks, and the third one returns a string with left-to-right marks. The original direction is restored in both cases at the end of the string.

It still depends on the client whether the writing direction will be visualized or not.